Analytic Formula for counter inside unique nested for loop for parallelization
Is there an analytic formula for c, such that the outermost loop on i can be parallelized so that c can be computed for any given iteration of i, j, k? N is known. The code is iterating through all unique triplets of some 1 dimensional array.
for i=1:N-2
    for j=i+1:N-1
        for k=j+1:N
            c++
            tripletarray[c] = oneDarray[i] * oneDarray[j] * oneDarray[k];


What do you mean by "analytic formula for c"? You can move c++ away of the last loop and increase it by N-(j+1)+1 = N-j (it is not clear in you pseudo code whether the end bound is included or not). Then you can move it out the second nested loop by summing all the algebraic terms. You get something like N-(i+1) + N-(i+2) + ... + N-(N-1) = (N-i) * (N-1-(i+1)) - (1+2+3+...) and 1+2+3+...+W = W*(W+1)/2. I think you can applies this again, but if this is too complex, then you can just run tasks in the first loop and compute c serially in it. Each tasks can run other tasks recursively.

Based on this, you can replace tripletarray[c] iteratively. The first step are just very basic math (though mistakes can be easily done). The last one is a bit complicated but certainly not unfeasible. What did you tried? And what was the problem when you did so? You should show your attempts to solve the problem.
